# Android, why raw file delete its contents (gesturs) after closing the app?

Tags: android, gesture

I am building an android app that lets the user draw a gesture,
and I am storing the gestures in a res/raw file to retrieve them later to make some process ( like open Facebook when draw "f" on the screen). I have the code to do all that but my problem is when I close the app the raw file deletes all the content (gestures and their names) that is stored by the user.

Therefore I need to keep the gestures and their names stored even if the user closes the App.

Sorry For bad English

Thx in advance.

The Code :

```
  submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            gesture=gv.getGesture();

            GestureLibrary store = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(NewDrawing.this,R.raw.gesture2);
            store.addGesture(t.getText().toString(), gesture);
            store.save();
```

and to retrieve the gestures i use the code :

```
GestureLibraries lib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(MainActivity.this,R.raw.gesture2);
    if (!lib.load()) {
        System.out.println("ERROR ,,,,,");
        finish();
    }
 // To test the raw file contents
    Set<String> set=lib.getGestureEntries();
    Object[] entries=set.toArray();

    for(int zz=0;zz < set.size();zz++)
    {
     System.out.println(">>>>"+entries[zz].toString());
    }
```

and the only entry is "o" character.

Comment: afaik, you can't store data in raw folder, it will be resetted when user relaunch the app. Try saving to sharedPreference instead.

Comment: Thx for ur reply ,,,please  how can i use sharedPreference  to store gestures and their names ,, and retrieve them later(put/install them in library to use recognize() function ..etc ??? )

Answer (score 0):

Don't use shared preferences or raw file to store data. What I suggest is to store on a local file. On the first run you can read the raw file. on the first save save the data to a file. And in the second run - just check if the file exist. if so - read data from it. If not read data again from raw.

```
if(localFileExist){
    data = localFile.read();
} else {
    data = readDataFromRaw();
}
```

Comment: i don't know how to create new file in sdcard and make the app load gestures from it !!